# sftp a file using shell script

Tags: sftp, expect

I have read through several threads (which have been helpful) and I'm still getting an error when trying to sftp a file (client wants it to be sftp'ed)

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
HOST=XX.XX.XX.XX
PORT=XXXX
USER=root
FILE=/tmp/RANDY

/usr/bin/expect<<EOD

spawn sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST
expect "sftp>"
spawn put $FILE
interact
EOD
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
spawn sftp -oPort=XXXX root@XX.XX.XX.XX
Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX...
sftp> spawn put /tmp/RANDY
couldn't execute "put": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn put /tmp/RANDY"
```

The file exists and is in the correct directory.

Answer (score 3):

The second `spawn` in your Expect script should be `send`, you should quote what you're sending to the spawned process, and you've left off the CR (Carriage Return, a.k.a. Enter):

```
send "put $FILE\r"
```

Also, you probably don't want the `interact` command. This probably makes more sense in its place:

```
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

where is password or authentication happening , For sure you have to authenticate first and then you should not get that error.