# Script for testing SFTP login status?

Tags: shell-script, login, sftp

I need to perform an automated backup task that connects to an SFTP server. The first stage involves testing the server connection by connecting to it. To be absolutely sure that it is connecting to the correct server, I am setting the `StrictHostKeyChecking` in ssh_config to yes.

So, when the connection to the SFTP server is made, how do I script the response from the server. The pseudo code is as follows:

```
If connection success
  disconnect
  initiate backup procedure

Else
  log error
  exit script
```

**Additional Info:**

I am using `ForceCommand internal-sftp` in the backup server's sshd_config, so running `ssh` command is out of the question.

Comment: I've provided a shell script in my answer that you can use the exit code from in the "connection success test". It includes the "disconnect" part. The only way I can think of to do the checking and other dependant logic branching inside the same sftp session is to script it with `expect`/`tcl` which never becomes elegant, as it is very hard to parse text and foresee any possible error conditions before you have found them the first time. Using for example `lftp`, the client itself checks the sftp-protocol's built-in status response codes. This makes catching errors easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most "SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) clients" are primarily/initially built for interactive use.

This doesn't mean that they lack batch mode options and such, but if you're looking for a script based file transfer over the SSH protocol, have a look at `scp` or `lftp` instead.

[`lftp` (homepage)](http://lftp.yar.ru/) is what I use in all my automated file transfers, and it has excellent error handling with reliable exit status. It was designed with reliability in mind.

There are tons of options to `lftp`, and you can supply any `ssh` options you like, such as `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=yes` if you specify a specific connection program to use.

Example:

```
MYSSHOPTIONS="-oStrictHostKeyChecking=yes"
CONNPROG="ssh -a -x ${MYSSHOPTIONS}"

cat > ${cmdfile}  <<- EOF
set sftp:max-packets-in-flight 16
set sftp:connect-program ${CONNPROG}
open -u ${remoteuser},${password-unless-pubkey-setup} sftp://${remotehost}
put localfile -o remotepathname
EOF

lftp -f ${cmdfile} > ${sendlog} 2>&1
RC=$?
if test $RC -ne 0
then
   failed
else
   reliably OK
fi
```

The example is a bit long. It creates a command file that sets some options and uploads one file `localfile` with optionally another `remotepathname` on the other side.

---

### sftp variant if you don't want to use `lftp`:

If you are interested in checking sftp login access you can use this template as a starting point for further experimenting:

```
#!/bin/sh -

mykey=/home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa
remusr=bupuser
remhost=server.destination.domain.com
tmpfile=/tmp/sftptest.$$

cleanup() {
  rm -f ${tmpfile}
}
trap cleanup 0

# This respects options from ~/.ssh/config (and possibly /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
# if that gets included from /etc/ssh/ssh_config), but options provided here prevail.
sftp -i $mykey -oPubkeyAuthentication=yes -oPasswordAuthentication=no -oKbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=yes ${remusr}@${remhost}  ${tmpfile} 2>&1
  dir
  exit
EOF
ST=$?

if test $ST -ne 0
then
  echo SFTP LOGIN FAILURE. RC=${ST} 1>&2
  exit $ST
fi

cat ${tmpfile} # or do some clever grepping on it

exit $ST
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this may be useful though I was expecting something more straight forward. Seems like all answers here seems to suggest that it is not possible to obtain status from sftp directly.

Comment: Well.. If you're mainly interested in validating that login is possible and that you are connecting to the correct server, scripting it with the normal `sftp` client from the openssh package is certainly possible if you have set up public key authentication and don't mind parsing stdout output for extra safety. If you want it robust and easy to expand I recommend `lftp` though. It is very easy and has many features you might want later on. It's just my example that is not so pretty.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will adopt your method and pipe `stdout` to `dev/null` so that cron will not send me email every time.

Comment: In the first example, there's no need to save the exit code in a separate variable. Instead of `program; RC=$?; if test $RC -ne 0; then ... fi` one can just use `if ! program; then ... fi`.

Comment: @Vilinkameni Valid comment, but if you want to use the exit status, perhaps as part of the error message, you need to store it.

Answer (score 2):

I've written expect and bash scripts to work this.... (though it can get fancier as mentioned above).

Bash script:
executed with three arguments: user, pass, and host. For example `./bwrap.sh ninja_user ninja_star1234 ninja.com`

The script creates a log file which later used for checking successful log in/out.

```
#!/bin/bash

# log file
log="connection_test.log"
if [ -f $log ];
then
    echo "Older file $log exists, removing and creating new..."
    rm -rf $log
    touch $log
else
    echo "Creating log file"
    touch $log
fi

# running expect script.
# arg 1 is user, arg 2 is pass, arg 3 is host 
./one.exp $1 $2 $3  >> $log

# checking log for connections 
if grep --quiet logout $log; then
    echo "connection successful, proceeding to backup" >> $log
else
    echo "connection failed, please check server" >> $log
    exit 1
fi
```

Now to the expect script, it has a timeout of 10 seconds, and I actually prefer to work w/o strict host key. If you do want to work with strict host key edit the relevant line and add an expect "yes/no" ....

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set user [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
set host [lindex $argv 2];

set timeout 10
# now ssh
spawn ssh $user@$host -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
match_max 100000 # Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"

expect "*$ "
send -- "whoami\r"
expect "<user name>"  # change user
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Hope this helps.

For `sftp` connection please:
add line to `bash` script where `$4` is port

```
./one.exp $1 $2 $3 $4 >> $log
```

add line to `expect` script:

```
set port [lindex $argv 3];
```

replace in expect script

```
spawn ssh $user@$host -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

with

```
spawn sftp $host@$user -o Port=$port StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

and

```
 expect "*$ "
```

with

```
expect "sftp>"
```

Since I do not have an SFTP server to test it on, the changes are made based on [this question]: [sftp a file using shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58106/sftp-a-file-using-shell-script)

Also, [expect homepage]: http://expect.sourceforge.net/  might be handy.

Lastly, reading your comment regarding a straight forward approach, it's possible to simply use `nc` and see if the host:port is up. For this you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# log file
log="connection_test.log"
if [ -f $log ];
then
    echo "Older file $log exists, removing and creating new..."
    rm -rf $log
    touch $log
else
    echo "Creating log file"
    touch $log
fi

# nc
nc_command=`nc -z -w 5 $1 $2 | tee -a $log`
if [[ $nc_command == *succeeded* ]];
then
    echo "Server is listening, ready for backup" | tee -a $log
else
    echo " Server seems to be offline, please check" | tee -a $log
    exit 1
fi
```

To run the last script use: `./test.sh host port`

Comment: Thank you. Can this be modified to connect with `sftp` command instead of `ssh`? Have updated my question to clarify that point.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Yes, please review edits at the bottom. Note that I do not have `sftp` to connect to, so this is based from examples.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow added lines needed to change to `sftp` and another solution using more straight forward approach.

Comment: +1 for the effort. `nc` is new to me. I will try to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If by chance, your backup script is based on Python, you might want to check out [check_sftp](https://github.com/Checkmk/checkmk/blob/master/active_checks/check_sftp), a so-called active check brought with Checkmk. It has the specific use-case of checking SFTP servers. Since it is based on Python and the pure-Python SSH implementation [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/), all you need is Python. It contains a few Checkmk specifics such as the password store and OMD_ROOT integration, which you might need to rip out to get it to work standalone. But it is somewhat sophisticated, including options to PUT or GET files or even compare timestamps on the server, so it might be worth a try. Since it adheres to the [Nagios Check Plugin Guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN78), you can rely on the exit code `0` for success.

Another Python-based option might be [Fabric](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#transfer-files) (which is also based on Paramiko), or using [the SFTP module of Paramiko](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#module-paramiko.sftp) directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could test `sftp` connectivity by just doing an `ssh` connection test:

```
if $(ssh -q belmin@mysever.bfworks.com exit)
then
    echo yes
fi
```

If the server does not allow `ssh`, you could do use `nmap` but that doesn't test key authentication:

```
nmap myserver.bfworks.com -PN -p ssh | grep 'open'
```

Comment: assuming that the SFTP server allows SSH login

Comment: Correct. I've used an `nmap` command line for servers that do not allow SSH login. I'll add that to the answer just in case it's useful. Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean the ssh shell subsystem. You can configure `sshd` to only allow (or force) `sftp` only. The user account can have a shell that only allows sftp, and so on.